# Using sed to fix format of date string

Tags: regex, bash, sed

The question specifically involves modifying a string of form

```
abc_MM-DD-YY_XX.jpg
```

(where XX can be comprised of two or three digits) to

```
xyz_YYYY-MM-DD_XXX.jpg
```

I was able to do this using:

```
sed 's/\(.*_\)\(.\{5\}\)-\([0-9][0-9]\)_\([0-9][0-9]\.\)/xyz_20\3-\2_0\4/'
```

I was wondering, though, if there are any better, perhaps more concise alternatives. Also, is using TRE (tagged regular expression) the only way sed can accomplish such a task? Thanks!

EDIT: Sorry, to clarify, the original string can either be in the format "abc_MM-DD-YY_XX.jpg" or "abc_MM-DD-YY_XXX.jpg", but the output format must be "abc_MM-DD-YY_XXX.jpg". So in the first case I would want to pad "XX" with a 0 and in the second case I would want to leave it be. I also realized that my expression doesn't work for the second case...

Comment: You don't need to capture the leading `.*_` since you ignore it, but you'd need to change the numbers in the replacement text if you don't capture the current `\1` any more.  However, that substitution command is doing a slightly different mapping from the one you describe, isn't it? It always adds a `0` before the `XX` and doesn't map `XXX` names at all, and it assumes that `XX` is a pair of digits.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ah, thanks for explaining. Also, you are absolutely right. It does not work with `XXX` names at all. Sorry for being so disorganized with this question.

Comment: It is easy enough to create a near clone of the first regex that does handle the XXX case (without adding the 0).  You can use `sed -e '...big-regex-1...' -e '...big-regex-2...', with backslashes and newlines to continue the command over several lines.  Note that the current regex assumes that XX is a pair of digits; your description could be more precise ('two or three characters' suggests non-digits, at least alphabetic characters, are allowed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work only in the century!

**Using `awk`**

I would use `awk` for that. It is simpler to use:

```
awk -F'[-_]' '$0="xyz_20"$4"-"$2"-"$3"_"sprintf("%03d",$5)' <<<'abc_03-24-15_11.jpg'
```

will give you:

```
xyz_2015-03-24_011.jpg
```

while:

```
awk -F'[-_]' '$0="xyz_20"$4"-"$2"-"$3"_"sprintf("%03d",$5)' <<<'abc_03-24-15_111.jpg'
```

will give you:

```
xyz_2015-03-24_111.jpg
```

what should be what you want.

*Explanation:*

I'm using either `-` or `_` as the field delimiter and simply reorganize the fields. To achieve the padding of and `XX` value to `XXX` I'm using `sprintf()`. (Thanks [Amadan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29245395/using-sed-to-fix-format-of-date-string/29245454?noredirect=1#comment46696543_29245454))

---

**Using `sed`**

Btw, you can simplify the `sed` command a lot if you would use the `-r` option and if you simply match sequences of not occurring characters:

```
sed -r 's/([^_]+)_([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^_]+)_([^.]+)/xyz_20\4-\2-\3_0\5/;' <<<'abc_03-24-15_12.jpg'
```

(This doesn't work perfectly since it does not solve the `XX` to `XXX` problem properly at the moment. Give me a minute ... )

To solve that you can simply append another `s` command:

```
s/0([0-9]{3})\./\1./
```

which will replace the sequence `0123` by `123`. The final command looks like this:

```
sed -r 's/([^_]+)_([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^_]+)_([^.]+)/xyz_20\4-\2-\3_0\5/;s/0([0-9]{3})\./\1./' <<<'abc_03-24-15_12.jpg'
```

Doesn't it look simpler using `-r` ;) (hihi)

Comment: I think he wanted `sprintf("%03d", $5)` ("XX can be comprised of two or three characters")

Comment: Hmm, too much guessing. If OP really wants that, he should tell. Probably it was just a typo.

Comment: It makes sense though, as turning `27` to `027` and leaving `100` alone will give you a proper numeric sort under a lexicographic comparator. Also, note the `0\4` in OP's original code, as an evidence of naive zero-padding. So, not so much guessing as cluework. :)

Comment: Yeah, after looking at question again I would say you are right!

Comment: Yeah, sorry for not making my question more clear. Also, the naive zero-padding doesn't even work if the input format is `XXX`... Whoops.

Comment: Thanks Amadan I finally got the problem. Are the commands working for you now?

Comment: Wow! This works perfectly. Thanks for the excellent explanation of how to use awk as well. I am slightly confused how the appended `s` command works though. Could you explain how it is trimming off the padded 0?

Comment: In the first `s` command I'm prepending a `0` to the `XX[X]` - regardless of if there are three or two `X`. This means the result can be for example `0111` if input has three `X` or `011` if input has two `X`.  In the second `s` I'm replacing a `0` followed by three numbers and a dot, by the three numbers and the dot but throw the zero away. If the first step lead to a three number sequence, the second `s` command simply does not apply because the pattern isn't found.